# Nested Conceptual Polymorphic Templates

Tags: c++, templates, nested, metaprogramming, c++20

Suppose I have compile time polymorphic inheritance structure:

```cpp
enum class Enum1 {
    Undefined = 0;
    /* ... */
};
enum class Enum2 {
    Undefined = 0;
    /* ... */
};

template<Enum1 A, Enum2 B>
struct Base {
    int state;
};

struct Derived : public Base <Enum1::Undefined, Enum2::Undefined>> {
    int statederived;
};
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```cpp
template<Base<Enum1, Enum2> DerivedTemplate>
using Function = std::function<void (DerivedTemplate&)>;
```

to accomplish:

```cpp
Function<Derived> & function;
```

And or create a class based upon these derived types with metaprogramming?

I could just create a class for each of these derived types, but I'd like to avoid that since I have around 50 of them.

Essentially, I would like to avoid clashes of different derived types with the same template arguments, while still enforcing the conceptual constraints.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for a constraint that ensures `Derived` must inherit from _any_ instantiation of `Base<Enum1, Enum2>`? Or are you trying to constrain it for a _specific_ instantiation, such as `Base<Enum1::Foo, Enum2::Bar>`?

Comment: The first, I think. But let me state clearly: In my implementation, there only really every exists one derived type of Enum1::Sometype, Enum2::Sometype, but technically that doesn't have to be the case. What I'd like to do is have a declaration of this Function template for each of those specific potential derived types, all in that one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Derived : public Base <Enum1::Undefined, Enum2::Undefined>> {
  int statederived;
};
```

This creates a mapping from `Derived` to `Base<Enum1::Undefined, Enum2::Undefined>`, but does not create a mapping the other way around.

Now you could do this

```
template<Enum e1, Enum e2, class D>
struct DerivedExtra:Base<e1, e2> {
  // can static cast to D to get Derived stuff
};

template<Enum1 e1, Enum2 e2>
struct Derived:
  DerivedExtra<e1, e2, Derived<e1, e2>>
{
  constexpr auto E1 = e1;
  constexpr auto E2 = e2;

  // common codes goes here
};
```

Write any custom Derived state by specializing `DerivedExtra`:

```
template<class D>
struct DerivedExtra<
  Derived<Enum1::Undefined, Enum2::Undefined>,
  D 
>:
  Base<Enum1::Undefined, Enum2::Undefined>
{
  int statederived;
};
```

Now we can take a list of `Enum1` and `Enum2` states and make the cartesian product.

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant = {};

constexpr auto enum1s = std::make_tuple(
  constant<Enum1::Undefined>,
  constant<Enum1::Defined>
);
constexpr auto enum2s = std::make_tuple(
  constant<Enum2::Undefined>,
  constant<Enum2::Defined>
);

constexpr auto e1xe2 = std::apply( [](auto...e1s) {
  return std::tuple_cat(
    std::apply([e1=e1s](auto...e2s) {
      return std::make_tuple(
        std::make_tuple(
          e1,
          e2s
        )...
      );
    }, enum2s )...
  );
}, enum1s );
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/MPhKd9ebT).

Using `e1xe2s` you can make a `std::tuple<std::function<void(Derived<a, b>)...>` or a variant of same, for example.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add a constraint on `Function` to let `DerivedTemplate` to be  derived from `Base<someEnum1, someEnum2>`, you can check if `DeriveTemplate&&` can be converted to `Base<someEnum1, someEnum2>&&` with template parameter `someEnum1` and `someEnum2`:

```cpp
template<Enum1 e1, Enum2 e2>
std::int32_t test(Base<e1, e2>&);
template<Enum1 e1, Enum2 e2>
std::int32_t test(Base<e1, e2> const&);
template<Enum1 e1, Enum2 e2>
std::int32_t test(Base<e1, e2>&&);
template<Enum1 e1, Enum2 e2>
std::int32_t test(Base<e1, e2> const&&);

template<typename T>
std::int8_t helper(...);
template<typename T>
std::int32_t helper(decltype(test(std::declval<T&&>()))*);

template<typename D>
inline constexpr bool is_base_of_Base_with_some_Enum = sizeof(helper<D>(nullptr)) == sizeof(std::int32_t);
```

and then you can change the type alias `Function` to:

```cpp
template<typename D>
struct FunctionImpl : std::enable_if<is_base_of_Base_with_some_Enum<D>, std::function<void(D&)>>{};

template<typename Derive>
using Function = typename FunctionImpl<Derive>::type;
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ec3sq3rj4).